# How common are indefinite pronouns in creole languages?

Tags: english, french, pronouns, creoles

I understand that creole languages from all parts of the world share many disparate features. Amongst them, how common are third–person, singular, indefinite pronouns (like the French “*on*”) in creole languages? What became of the French “*on*” in Haitian Creole (*Kreyòl*)?